# Recycler View Position Bottom of ImageView

Tags: java, android

I'm learning Android Material from Slidenerd's video on Youtube. I got a problem when learn to make Recycler View on Drawer. But the position of Recycler View can't bottom of Image View. I want to throw that after the ImageView like another Material Design app. Let see the screenshot.

[image]

This is my code:

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEE"
    tools:context="com.balinez.wdharmana.doahindu.NavigationDrawerFragment">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:background="#F88C00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_galungan"
        />


    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</FrameLayout>
```

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/listIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Doa Sehari-hari"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <include android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" style="@style/AppTheme.Base" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.balinez.wdharmana.doahindu.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Let's share if you also has same problem. Thanks for advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it really not necessary to user `FrameLayout` as your parent, you can use `RelativeLayout` like I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="#EEE"

             tools:context="com.balinez.wdharmana.doahindu.NavigationDrawerFragment">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:background="#F88C00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/beach"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```